# c# .NET 4.5 HttpWebRequest for portable crossplatforms

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, cross-platform, system.net.httpwebrequest

I cannot change user agent of HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "test";
```

Always throw exception. Someone have idea how solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use request.UserAgent property to set the user agent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The property UserAgent does not exist for portable version of HttpWebRequest, that is the problem.

Comment: what exception are you getting? Which platform is this?